# How can I find a specific variable coefficient for an individual in a fixed effects model?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, regression-coefficients, plm

I have specified the following model in R using the plm package.

```
fixed<- plm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = mydata, 
        index = c("City", "Date"), model="within")
summary(fixed)
```

I think the model specification works well for my purposes, but now I want to know what the coefficient of `x1` is for each `City` specified as an individual in the panel dataset.

I know I can use `fixef(fixed)` but that only provides the constant terms by `City`. What I want is the coefficient estimate for `x1` for each individual in `City`.

I have been looking for hours online and have tried dozens of different search terms to try and figure this out. I really appreciate any and all help.

Comment: There is essential information missing from your question. Most importantly, how is your data structured? In other words and unless you use Bayesian MCMC (or a variant), you need at least 5 or 6 observations per individual to be able to identify a model at this high level of disaggregation. That said, hierarchical and/or multilevel models offer a solution. Good intros include Gelman and Hill's "Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models" or Judith Singer's article (https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `plm(..., model = "within")` you get the within model (or fixed effects model) and it estimates same coefficients for all entities. If you want different coefficients for the entities, you can use `pvcm()` to fit a OLS model per individual.

Building upon the example from the help page (`?pvcm`):

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")

form <- log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp
summary(plm(form, data = Produc, model = "within"))
## [...]
## Coefficients:
##              Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
## log(pcap) -0.02614965  0.02900158 -0.9017    0.3675    
## log(pc)    0.29200693  0.02511967 11.6246 < 2.2e-16 ***
## log(emp)   0.76815947  0.03009174 25.5273 < 2.2e-16 ***
## unemp     -0.00529774  0.00098873 -5.3582 1.114e-07 ***
## [...]

pvcm(form, data = Produc, model = "within") # individual coefficients
## Coefficients:
##                (Intercept)  log(pcap)    log(pc)  log(emp)       unemp
## ALABAMA            8.49604 -1.4426440  0.2795010  1.835250  0.00735450
## ARIZONA            4.66528 -0.1627084 -0.0052207  1.075828 -0.00365798
## ARKANSAS           3.24565 -0.5056503  0.3212473  1.234017  0.00149221
## CALIFORNIA         0.27935  0.2639377  0.2484033  0.699135 -0.01074510
## [...]

###### same using OLS on splitted data for first entity (ALABAMA):
l <- split(Produc, Produc$state)
plm(form, data = l[[1]], model = "pooling")
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)   log(pcap)     log(pc)    log(emp)       unemp 
##   8.4960384  -1.4426440   0.2795010   1.8352498   0.0073545
```

Comment: I do not have enough observations to run the pvcm.

On the larger data set, when I run plm:

`Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
  duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning message:
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")`

I used this to remove duplicates

`mydata.plm<-mydata.lm[!duplicated(mydata.lm[c("City", "Date")]),]`

Is there a better way to remove duplicates that will allow me to run a fixed effects model?

Comment: 1) Well, then you just do not have enough observations, i.e. you want to estimate more regressors than there are observations. You would either need to gather more observations or decrease the number of regressors (if there are "unimportant" variables you can leave out). However, would you trust an estimate that is just based on a few observations, say 5? 2) Seems like a easy and plausible way to me.

Comment: Some Cities have a number of observations that in the hundreds while other Cities have only 2 or 3 observations. Would these small cities create this error?

Would you recommend creating a subset with data for Cities with a large amount of observations? Or would this be a drastically different model to the fixed effects model you described to me earlier?

Comment: Yes, cities with too few observations create this error. If you leave those out, well, you do not get estimates for those.. you could then run the FE model over the same reduced data and see if you get drastically different results from the FE estimates (same coefficients for all included cities, thus information about the cities with too few obs is not taken into account - this could be a problem if the obs are not missing at random - look at the panel attrition problem). Maybe, look also at `plm::pooltest`.